# YouCompleteMe does not work for python

Tags: python, vim, vim-plugin, youcompleteme, python-jedi

I'm not sure if this is some kind of bug (probably not, otherwise everyone would complain) and without a google account, I can't use the google group, so I try my luck here in the hope that somebody has a suggestion.

I have YouCompleteMe installed with clang-completer and stuff works fine for C, C++. Now I edit a `.py` file, and the only completions offered are the words already in the buffer. No semantic completion. `:YcmCompleter` prints `No semantic completer exists for filetypes: [u'py']`. I have removed everything except the following from my `.vimrc`:

```
call pathogen#infect()
Helptags

filetype on
```

To no avail. Does anybody have an idea how to better diagnose the problem?

**Edit:** I realised I did not have `jedi` installed. So I ran `pip install jedi` which strangely changed nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out hat I had an `ftplugin` for `.py` files which would set the filetype to `py` instead of `python` as is intended. Disabling it solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Python is an interpreted language.

The autocompletion works only for objects in the python library (eg: os, time,...) and in your vim buffer.

If you are using a buildout, you can add vim-buildout in your vim bundle => https://github.com/FBruynbroeck/vim-buildout

This plugin add your eggs (/parts/omelette) in syspath. (YouCompleteMe uses syspath vim for the python autocompletion)

Personally, I use jedi (autocompletion library). YouCompleteMe is too big for me. (I develop only in python for this moment)

Comment: Well, autocompletion for the standard library would be a start, but I don't even get that.

Comment: Did you have python-dev on your local machine ? (sudo apt-get install python-dev)

Comment: I am on OSX, but python is installed ofc.